# How to get Heart points in google fit REST API

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to get heart points from google fit REST API. I see that heart rate data in google fit app (110 bmg) but i am getting empty data through the API.

**API**: `https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate`

**BODY**:

```
{
  "aggregateBy": [{
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.heart_rate.bpm",
    "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_minutes"
  }],
  "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
  "startTimeMillis": 1580533200000, // feb 01 2020
  "endTimeMillis": 1582866000000 // feb 28 2020
}
```

Result :

i am getting empty records like :

```
{
    "bucket": [ 
....
{
            "startTimeMillis": "1580619600000",
            "endTimeMillis": "1580706000000",
            "dataset": [
                {
                    "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.heart_minutes.summary:com.google.android.gms:aggregated",
                    "point": []
                }
            ]
        },
....
    ]
}
```

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I got it. It took some time to update the API i guess, I had to update the body:

```
{
  "aggregateBy": [{
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.heart_minutes"
    //"dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_minutes"
  }],
  "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
  "startTimeMillis": 1580533200000, // feb 01 2019
  "endTimeMillis": 1580878800000 // feb 6 2020 1582866000000 // feb 28 2020
}
```

Comment: "It took some time to update the API i guess, I had to update the body:" What do you mean?

Comment: I synced heartrate from the app to googlefit, but it could took few minutes to fetch those synced data from REST API.

Comment: Can I ask - in your answer did it work with the `dataSourceId` commented out like that? Also where did you find the documentation for the `dataSourceId` value you used (`derived:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_minutes`)? I'm trying to get heart rate summary but have no idea what to use for data source, can't find any documentation

Comment: @JamesAllen you can remove the commented code i.e., you can remove //datasourceid line completely. not sure where i found the document. It is hard to find proper document. i looked at blood glucose examples and after multiplr trial and errors found this solution.